# How to join two queries to display as a single table iwth two headers in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I wanted to join these two block of codes into a single table when queried which displays the most common location for the pickup from different table which is (January and February) How would it be possible?
These are my two codes:

```
SELECT pulocationid AS MostCommonPickupLocation
FROM jan
GROUP BY pulocationid
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

AND

```
SELECT pulocationid AS MostCommonPickupLocation
FROM feb
GROUP BY pulocationid
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

[I want these two tables side by side and be able to do display them both by using one single query only](https://i.stack.imgur.com/efdJk.png)

[Expected oUTPUT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PLunC.png)

The expected out is to have two column headers which is January and February which contains the generated values from the above two separated queries I have provided. How to combine them together?

| January | February |
| --- | --- |
| 3 | 43 |

Comment: Use [UNION ALL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/union.html) to combine two queries .

Comment: I'm guessing you want jan and feb as headers but you don't say.

Comment: Please show expected output

Comment: @P.Salmon Yesss

Comment: I have included my expected output now

Comment: @Luuk I tried that but it should have two column headers one for january and feb

Comment: Desired output could also have bene posted as text, not as an image.... 

Comment: @Luuk What do you mean? I just can't figure out how to join them together that's why I posted it as an image. Any tips how to do that? :(

Comment: @mariakz: see my edit. (and my answer with some other titles, but you can fix that )

Answer (score 1):

When you do this:

```
SELECT 
   jan.pulocationid AS January,
   feb.MostCommonPickupLocationFeb AS February
FROM jan
CROSS JOIN (
  SELECT pulocationid AS MostCommonPickupLocationFeb
  FROM feb
  GROUP BY pulocationid
  ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
  LIMIT 1
) feb
GROUP BY jan.pulocationid
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

you can expect to see output like:

| January | February |
| --- | --- |
| 3 | 43 |

NOTE: When the query from January does not have results, there will be no output from this query.

Comment: hi. it says error in my sql syntax near 'GROUP BY pulocation
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
 LIMIT 1'. I just folllowed the code that you have provided :(

Comment: I did forget to add  the aliasses. These are needed because you have two fields named `pulocationid `, and MySQL needs to distinguish them.

Comment: it then says Unknown column 'feb.pulocation' in 'field list' :(

Comment: it's hard to test a query without actual data .... 

Comment: What do you think has been the cause why am I getting that error message? So maybe I can check?

Comment: I just basically want to combine the above queries in a single table with two header columns :((

Comment: see my last edit